# Link_to in view that redirects to another view by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

So i have 2 models Users and books. Books has user_id,name, User has name,adress. Both have views. I did create a link_to in user view to redirect to books view, but i want to redirect by id.

What i mean if i click in User1 link_to, i want to view only user1 books(books that have only user_id:1 if it is possible to see the most recent created at the beginning, so if i have created book.id=5 would get first and book.id=1 would be lastone).

User model:

```
Class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :books
```

Book Model:

```
Class Book < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
```

Controller book show:

```
def show 
 @book = Book.all
end
```

if you need anything else, just ask in comments and i will edit. Also sorry if im not explaining correctly.

Comment: Id need to see what you have in your controller but shooting blindly:
`@books = @user.books` in your user show page should give you all books associated with the user. you can then call `.order(created_at: :desc)` to sort them

Comment: @Haumer What i want to do is get all books whit user.id on the one i click the link_to, so it gets me to my book.index_html page where are listed all books. Should i change my book show to `@books = @user.books` and in link_to add `.order(created_at: :desc)` ? Im new at ruby and rails ,sorry if im not getting it rigth.

Comment: @CodrinM You could either do this as a filter on the same route (i.e. `/books?user_id=1`), or as a separate route (i.e. `/users/1/books`). Which approach fits your use case better?

Comment: If you want to stay on the same page you might want to just add the user_id as a param and then find that user in the controller and filter for that users books.


`if params[:user_id].present?
@books = User.find(params[:user_id]).books
else
@books = Book.all
end `

Comment: Also, your "book show" action doesn't really fit the conventions; displaying `Book.all` is an **index** action, not a *show* action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `books#index` controller action

```
def index
  @books = Book.all
  @books = @books.where(user_id: params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id].present?
end
```

And in your `users#show` view

```
link_to "This user books", books_path(user_id: @user.id)
```

So if you will go to `/books` you will see all books

But if you click the link on user's page -- you will see only this user books

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best soluction is leave the default methods and create a new one:

```
def show_user_books
  @books = Book.where(user_id:params[:user_id]).order(created_at: :desc) if params[:user_id].present?

  redirect_to books_path 
end
```

Comment: New instance of controller will be created after redirect. How will you access to this instance variable?

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. What route(s) and action(s) are there, why should `@books` be left as `nil` if there's no `user_id`, and how is the `@books` variable going to be accessed after a redirect?